# How to min/max a character build

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

Firstly, a disclaimer: I do not find much joy in highly optimised characters that can slay everything with ease at the table.  However, the idea of creating such a character (or making the most out of a suboptimal choice - e.g. using poor weapons or unconventional playstyle) I find to be very intriguing.

I am wondering where one starts with this sort of endeavour - how to test a particular build, figuring out which choices are more worthwhile mechanically, etc.

**Can anyone provide a good resource for learning to "theorycraft" in DnD?**

Comment: Hi Wharf Rat. This question is off-topic for our Stack Exchange. It's what is referred to as a shopping question, where you ask for a list of resources. Google is a great way to find such resources, RPG Stack Exchange is about asking a question about a specific problem that *should* have a specific, correct answer.

Comment: Luke is correct, however if you have a particular build you need help optimizing, we can help with that. When/if you decide you do want help, see [this meta Q&A](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8123/how-do-i-ask-a-good-character-build-optimization-question-for-dd-5e/8124#8124) for help with how to ask that well here.